# wordpress container not centered in IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I'm using WP on one page of my site and for some reason the content isn't centered; in every browser other than IE it works, but for some reason in IE it doesn't. I've been looking at code for so long I know it's something simple, but cannot figure out what it is. [Here is the site in question](http://clairekhoury.com/selection/)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid which is triggering quirks mode in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **@j08691** pointed out [the problem is that](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fclairekhoury.com%2Fselection%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) you have a `<div>` element before your doctype which is causing IE to display with [Quirks Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can't place a div anywhere except for within the body.

Just change:

```
<div id="container">
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

To:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

*nothing* should precede your doctype, not even white-space

Comment: That is awesome, thanks! Very easy fix, just had to move a line of code outside my div.